# How to get the highest version number / tag in PHP

Tags: php

Because the Bitbucket API doesn't provide a method to get the latest tag for a repository I find myself having to get it from an array of all tags.

How do you do it?

I have tried [max](http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php) but it doesn't work for certain numbers e.g.

```
max(['1.0.8', '1.0.9', '1.0.10']);
```

returns '1.0.9'.

I know the tags will only ever be three numbers `a.b.c` they won't have other semver accepted strings like alpha etc. because of the way we do tags for our repos.

So how do you do it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
$versions = ['1.0.8', '1.0.9', '1.0.10'];
usort($versions, 'version_compare');
echo end($versions);
```

See http://php.net/version_compare

If you don't feel like modifying the array:

```
echo array_reduce($versions, function ($highest, $current) {
    return version_compare($highest, $current, '>') ? $highest : $current;
});
```

Comment: Oh wow this part of [version_compare](http://php.net/version_compare)  is excellent `If a part contains special version strings these are handled in the following order: any string not found in this list < dev < alpha = a < beta = b < RC = rc < # < pl = p`.

Comment: It's surprisingly powerful, yes.

Answer (score 1):

By using the [`version_compare`](http://php.net/manual/function.version-compare.php) function:

```
function maxVersion($array)
{
    $max = null;

    foreach ($array as $version) {
        if (version_compare($max, $version) === -1) {
            $max = $version;
        }
    }

    return $max;
}

print(maxVersion(['1.0.8', '1.0.9', '1.0.10']));
// returns "1.0.10"
```

Answer (score -1):

Because you are dealing with Strings here rather than numbers, you will not get the result you require. You could try the following:

```
$version_numbers = str_replace(".","",['1.0.8', '1.0.9', '1.0.10']);
$max = max($version_numbers);
```

If you are always dealing with a fixed ***a.b.c*** structure then by replacing the decimal point you will get a series of integers that will let you determine the maximum relatively easily

Comment: When you find out that `1010` is the maximum of those 3, what will you return? `1010` ? How will you make it `1.0.10`